# Connected components of natural numbers set with subspace topology

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Consider $\Bbb R$ with usual topology. Now consider $\Bbb N$ (set of natural numbers) with subspace topology. Let $x \in \Bbb N$ be a point in $\Bbb N$. The result says that the only possible connected set containing $x$ is {$x$} only. Why is that so?

Comment: Are you claiming that, since $\Bbb R$ is connected (with respect to its usual topology) and since $1\in\Bbb R$, then $\Bbb R=\{1\}$? I seriously doubt that.

Comment: @Jose I guess I was not able to make myself clear. I have edited my question. Please have a look.

Comment: If $X \subset \Bbb{N}$ contains $x$ as well as other points, then $X = \{ x\} \cup (X - \{x\}$) is a decomposition of $X$ into two disjoint non-empty open sets.

Comment: The only connected subset of $\Bbb N$ contains $x$ is $\{x\}$ yes.

Comment: @Alex How are {x} and X-{x} open sets in X?

Comment: Do you understand what it means for e.g. $\{x\}$ to be open in the subspace topology?

Comment: @Alex Yes, it means {x} can be written as $\Bbb N$ intersection some open set in $\Bbb R$. Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the topology of $\Bbb{N}$ is discrete, i.e., all its subsets are open. To see this it suffices to note that any singleton is open in the subspace topology, and then realize that any subset is a union of singletons.

Now if $X \subset \Bbb{N}$ contains $x$ as well as other points, then $X = \{ x\} \cup (X - \{x\}$) is a decomposition of $X$ into two disjoint non-empty open sets.

Comment: Okay...now I understand it. Can I ask you one more thing? How to show the same result for $\Bbb Q$?

Comment: @Esha See e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1755992/mathbb-q-is-totally-disconnected-what-is-the-open-set-in-subspace-of-mathb

Comment: I saw the answer referred by you in the comments. It had excellent explanation. Just one more thing. Does that mean that in any arbitrary topological space, "being a subspace of" is transitive when all have subspace topology ?

Comment: @Esha Yes, that is the case.